# Does the set of empty set contain set of empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

well I guess it would be easier to show an example of what I am asking:

Is this sentence True or False ?

$$\{\emptyset\}\subseteq \{1,\{\emptyset\}\}$$

Edit:

following the same logic I had before I got the answer to the original question in the post I tried to solve this 2 questions :
[edit - 2 questions photo -  please edit to show it to everyone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6Wqz.png)

and on the left question I figured the answer was True

and on the right question I figured the answer was True also

but after reading the answers it seems to me that it cannot be that both are true but I can't explain why... 
Am  I correct on this one ?

Comment: Please make the image inline by putting "!" before the square brackets of example.

Comment: @Kumar New users do not have the ability to place inline images.  This is in an attempt to curb the effect of spam bots and trolls among other things.

Comment: The end result for the mathematics involved here is to recognize that the "depth" here matters, the number of braces...  Each of $\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},\dots$ are distinct, different, nonequal sets.  Then, recognize that $a\in A$ is asking specifically if $a$ is an *element* of $A$ which is different than asking if $a$ is an element of an element of $A$ or deeper, i.e. that it is asking if the element $a$ appears "at the topmost level."  Similarly, $A\subseteq B$ is asking if every element of $A$ (*at the topmost level*) is also an element (*at the topmost level*) of $B$

Comment: In your case, $\emptyset$ is an element of the set on the left but is not an element of the set on the right in exactly the same way that $\{3\}$ is not a subset of $\{1,\{3\}\}$.

Comment: I think I got it , although {} is still a litlle bit tricky for me.
thanks guys

Comment: I've just realized that I've heard 'contain' used for both "has an element' and 'has a subset', with only context to distinguish which is meant. That makes this question, as stated in the title with words and not symbols, very tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask if this is correct:

$$\{\emptyset\}\subseteq \{1, \{\emptyset\}\}$$

It is not. Indeed, $\emptyset \in \{\emptyset\}$ while $\emptyset \notin\{1, \{\emptyset\}\}$.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply !

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 cases :

(1) either ***all*** the elements of the set on the left are also elements of the set on the right, and in that case , the statement is true ( set on the left is included in set on the right)

OR

(2) ***at leat one*** element of the set on the left ***is not*** an element of the set on the right.

Here we are on case 2. Indeed I can exhibit the element " empty set" that belongs to the set on the left but not to the set on the right.

Note: the empty set is a set, but it can also be an element of a set; that is what happens here; and, in fact, it is the only element of the set on the left.

The set on the left can be compared to a box with an empty box inside. The empty box is empty. But the box with an empty box inside is not empty, it has 1 element ( namely, the empty box).

[image]

Comment: but if you mark {empty set} = A 
then isn't the right side says : {1,A} ?

Comment: @Maor.- I've added a picture to my post. Hope it helps.